# mysql getting specific row and column

Tags: python, mysql

Is there any way to get the selected number where i have the plant name(combi-8) and the column name(Floor Disinfeciton)

[image]

Comment: This is one of the most basix SQL queries. What problem are you having?

Comment: `SELECT colname_you_want FROM tablename WHERE other_column = 'value to look for'`

Comment: yes it's very easy, when i use MySQL workbench i got 0, but when i use the same syntax I got string value 'Berko-46'.

Comment: You must be putting the wrong column name in `colname_you_want`. Post your Python code.